# Azure Mobile Services-Authentication Error

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

While trying to log into Azure Mobile Service using authentication token I get this error: "The authentication token's signature was malformed or signed by a different key." I am using Facebook as the Authentication provider.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. I'm using Windows 8 SDK for Windows Store Apps.

Comment: How are you trying to log in? Which client platform are you using?

Comment: Its a Windows store app, just updated the question..

Comment: Which of the overloads of the `LoginAsync` method are you using? One which only takes the provider, or one which also takes a token?